# Julia: why is GC slow with large number of mutable structs in memory

Tags: julia

Why is garbage collection so much slower when a large number of mutable structs are loaded in memory as compared with non-mutable structs? The object tree should have the same size in both cases.

```
julia> struct Foo
           a::Float64
           b::Float64
           c::Float64
       end

julia> mutable struct Bar
           a::Float64
           b::Float64
           c::Float64
       end

julia> @time dat1 = [Foo(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for i in 1:1e9];
  9.706709 seconds (371.88 k allocations: 22.371 GiB, 0.14% gc time)

julia> @time GC.gc(true)
  0.104186 seconds, 100.00% gc time

julia> @time GC.gc(true)
  0.124675 seconds, 100.00% gc time

julia> @time dat2 = [Bar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for i in 1:1e9];
 71.870870 seconds (1.00 G allocations: 37.256 GiB, 73.88% gc time)

julia> @time GC.gc(true)
 47.695473 seconds, 100.00% gc time

julia> @time GC.gc(true)
 41.809898 seconds, 100.00% gc time
```

Answer (score 5):

Non-mutable structs may be stored directly inside an Array. This will never happen for mutable structs. In your case, the `Foo` objects are all stored directly in `dat1`, so there is effectively just a single (albeit very large) allocation reachable after creating the Arary.

In the case of `dat2`, every `Bar` object will have its own piece of memory allocated for it and the Array will contain references to these objects. So with `dat2`, you end up with 1G + 1 reachable allocations.

You can also see this using `Base.sizeof`:

```
julia> sizeof(dat1)
24000000000

julia> sizeof(dat2)
8000000000
```

You'll see that `dat1` is 3 times as large, as every array entry contains the 3 `Float64`s directly, while the entries in `dat2` take up just the space for a pointer each.

As a side note: For these kinds of tests, it is a good idea to use `BenchmarkTools.@btime` instead of the built-in `@time`. As it removes the compilation overhead from the result and also runs your code multiple times in order to give you a more representative result:

```
@btime dat1 = [Foo(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for i in 1:1e6]
  2.237 ms (2 allocations: 22.89 MiB)

@btime dat2 = [Bar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) for i in 1:1e6]
  6.878 ms (1000002 allocations: 38.15 MiB)
```

As seen above, this is particularly useful to debug allocations. For `dat1` we get 2 allocations (one for the `Array` instance itself and one for the chunk of memory where the array stores its data), while with `dat2` we have an additional allocation per element.

Comment: Any idea why creating `dat1` has 300k allocations? Is that compilation?

Comment: @OscarSmith probably, yes. For anything more than simply toying around, you'll really want to use `btime` from `BenchmarkTools`, which will take care of removing compilation from the benchmark result and will also run your code multiple times to get a better estimate.